# Automatic inheritance of bindings in Racket subclasses

Tags: oop, inheritance, racket

I'm having a class with several subclasses that all uses methods and fields from the parent-class. Is there a "correct" way of handling this?

So far I've been using `(inherit method1 method2 ...)` in each subclass.

I've searched in vain for a way that the parent-class can force the subclasses to inherit the bindings, and I understand that that might be bad style.

Not very experienced with Racket or OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods are inherited even if you don't use `inherit`.
To call a method from a super class, one can use `(send this method arg1 ...)`.
The form `(inherit method)` inside a class form will make the method available in form `(method arg1 ...)` inside the body. This is not just a convenient shorthand, but is also more efficient than `(send this method)`.

I am unaware of forms that package names to inherit, but you can roll your own with a little macro. Here is an example:

```
(define-syntax (inherit-from-car stx) 
  (datum->syntax stx '(inherit wash buy sell)))

(define car% (class object%
               (define/public (wash) (display "Washing\n"))
               (define/public (buy)  (display "Buying\n"))
               (define/public (sell) (display "Selling\n"))
               (super-new)))

(define audi% (class car% (super-new)
                (inherit-from-car)
                (define/public (wash-and-sell)
                  (wash)
                  (sell))))

(define a-car (new audi%))
(send a-car wash-and-sell)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! 

I thought about trying to do something similar, but didn't know of datum->syntax.

I'll leave the question open for a while to see if there's any other comers.

Comment: I think Racket's class system requires inherited methods to be listed explicitly.  Other class systems may have different requirements.  Racket's is a little funny because the classes are runtime values: you can make new classes on the fly.  Example: mixins.  (See: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/classes.html) Unfortunately, this flexibility comes at a price in that the compiler doesn't currently know what methods are available in the superclass, given the superclass is a runtime value rather than a compile-time one.  But you can always `send` a message, by the way.  e.g. `(send this wash)`